# wordpress call to undefine function

Tags: php, wordpress

On event I am loading a file in a page which should include a shortcode for a chat. The issue is that it says call to an undefined function. The shortcode is working fine on the same page, but when is loaded from a different file (same directory) it doesn't work.

I tried this:

```
<?php 
$file="/web/htdocs/.../home/wp-content/plugins/quick-chat";
plugin_dir_url($file); ?>
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: You need to include the file that has that function on the page as plugin_dir_url() is not a standard function.

Comment: you should include wp-config.php file

Comment: @TimWithers yes, but it is a shortcode for an entire plugin, I included the main file, then there are other undefined functions. Is there a way to include the entire plugin?

Comment: @RezaSh Still get the Fatal error: Call to undefined function quick_chat() in /web/htdocs/www.....com/home/wp-content/themes/child_care_creative/f.php on line 19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was a problem with that specific plugin who couldn't be called from other document. With other plugins it is working. Thanks!